# Magento 2.4.5 Install Problem on CPanel of LINUX Server

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, linux, cpanel

I need to install Magento 2.4.5 on my website.

I have access to terminal. and uploaded the installation pack to public html.

I am some new to Magento.

I have 3 problems:

1- my composer version is 2.4.4 and when in try to update to 2.5.5 with this command "composer self-update", I got this Error
[image]

2- The Magento installer also can not install because of the old composer version
[image]

3-  also the Magento on my Cpanel is an old version and I think I have to install through the Terminal
[image]

I don't how can I fix it

please help

Comment: This will help you more : https://magecomp.com/blog/upgrade-magento-2-composer/

Comment: Not fixed. I received error in step one

Comment: I think the first problem is the permission issue. Try the command "sudo" before your command.

Comment: thanks for your guides

Comment: I check permisssion but 404 error still not fixed